# Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face. AddFaceToLargeFaceListAsync from FTP with MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using the WS of Microsoft FaceAPI.
When using a FileStream all works well but I have to read images from FTP so I am using MemoryStream.
I always ends with this exception :

```
{Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException: Image size is too small.(InvalidImageSize)
```

here is my method for creating MemoryStream. Is it correct??

```
 public MemoryStream GetFileStream(string filePath, string userName, string password)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"getting file stream : {filePath}");
        MemoryStream ftpStream = null;
        try
        {
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            FtpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(filePath) as FtpWebRequest;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

            ftpStream = new MemoryStream();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            responseStream.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"getting file stream : {filePath} " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return ftpStream;

    }
```

and here  is the task where I am calling the WS of FaceAPI

```
  using (MemoryStream fStream = ftpService.GetFileStream(imgPath, customerConfig.FTPUserName, customerConfig.FTPPassword))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (fStream != null)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("fStream Length : " + imgPath + " {" + fStream.Length + "}");
                                    var faces = await faceServiceClient.AddFaceToLargeFaceListAsync(listId, fStream); //==>> GET ME The EXCEPTION
                                    if (fStream != null)
                                    {
                                        fStream.Close();
                                    }
                                    if (urlFaceID.ContainsKey(imgPath) == false)
                                        urlFaceID.Add(imgPath, faces.PersistedFaceId.ToString());
                                }

                            }
                            catch (FaceAPIException ex)
                            {

                                if (ex.ErrorCode.Equals("ConcurrentOperationConflict"))
                                {
                                    imageList.Add(imgPath);

                                }

                                else if (ex.ErrorCode.Equals("RateLimitExceeded"))
                                {
                                    imageList.Add(imgPath);
                                }
                                else if (ex.ErrorMessage.Contains("more than 1 face in the image."))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("more than 1 face in the image.");
                                }
                                if (InvalidUrlFaceID.ContainsKey(imgPath) == false)
                                {
                                    InvalidUrlFaceID.Add(imgPath, null);
                                }

                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                if (fStream != null)
                                {
                                    fStream.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I dont Know if I am reading the MemoryStream right.
cant find any solution for that 
I hope some one will answer. 
THank you all

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks mostly correct, but you're forgetting that both the read and write pointers are advanced for the `MemoryStream` whenever you write.  In other words the returned value of `GetFileStream` is already pointing to the end of the stream as you've written.   All you need to change is to 'rewind' the stream before returning.

```
public MemoryStream GetFileStream(string filePath, string userName, string password)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"getting file stream : {filePath}");
    MemoryStream ftpStream = null;
    try
    {
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        FtpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(filePath) as FtpWebRequest;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

        ftpStream = new MemoryStream();
        ...
        ftpStream.Position = 0; // <-- ADD THIS LINE
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"getting file stream : {filePath} " + ex.ToString());
    }

    return ftpStream;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But when I debug the ftpStream I find that the ftpStream.Position is already equals to 0.

Comment: What is the value of `ftpStream.Length`?

Comment: it's the value of the size of the file exemple 435515